# Manejo de arreglos en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, matrices

Hola necesito ayuda con estos dos ejercicios de manejo de arrays en javascript, se pide llenar las matrices con  se muestran en las imagenes siguiendo el camino de rojo marcado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el codigo siguiente:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
        var con=1;
        var n=window.prompt("ingrese tamaño matriz");
        var mat=new Array(n);
        for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
                mat[i] = new Array(n);
               }
        
        var matriz="";
        for(let f=0;f<n;f++)
            {
                for(let c=0;c<n;c++)
            {
                
                mat[f][c]=con;
                con++
                matriz+=mat[f][c]+"     ";    
            }
                       
            matriz+="\n";       
            }
        window.alert(matriz);
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No podido llegar a una solucion y si alguien pudiera darme una mano seria de mucha ayuda de antemano muchas gracias, con este codigo para el ejecicio 1 al llegar al tamaño de la matriz la posicion vuelve al principio la matriz final termina de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muestras el código pero no explicas cual es el problema con ese.

Comment: ¿Cual de las dos opciones quieres solucionar?
La fácil es la primera, simplemente ve invertiendo el orden de llenado de la horizontal.